# CSRF token missing or incorrect AJAX / DJANGO

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Can someone help me with this problem?

I have list of tasks in my page. Every task has there own form where users can send comments. When I add new task AJAX update list of comments and then I try to send comment by form and it raise **error : “CSRF token missing or incorrect”**. In any other situation forms work well. I have `{% csrf_token %}` in my form. It seems like I need send CSRF in AJAX. Where I did mistake? Why it didnt work?

**JS:**

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

// TASK

$(function () {
    var loadForm = function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr("data-url"),
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#modal").modal("show");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#modal .modal-content").html(data.html_task_form);
            }
        });
    };

    var saveForm = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: {
                data: form.serialize(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
            },
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#task-list").html(data.html_task);
                    $("#modal").modal("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $("#modal .modal-content").html(data.html_task_form);
                }
            }
        });
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    // Create TASK
    $("#task-add-button").click(loadForm);
    $("#modal").on("submit", ".js-task-add-form", saveForm);
    // Update TASK
    $("#task-list").on("click", "#js-edit-task-button", loadForm);
    $("#modal").on("submit", ".js-task-edit-form", saveForm);
});
```

CODE FOR COMMENT ADD:

**views.py:**

```
def task_comment_add(request, project_code, task_code):
    data = dict()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code)
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_code)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            task.comments.add(comment)
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            data['html_task_comment'] = render_to_string('project/task_comment_list.html' {'task': group_task})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {'project': project, 'task': task, 'form': form}
    data['html_task_comment_form'] = render_to_string('project/task_comment_form.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**JS:**

```
// TASK COMMENT ADD
$(".task-comment-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.preventDefault());
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var current_group = form.closest('.custom-list-group');
            if (data.form_is_valid) {
                current_group.find(".task-comments").html(data.html_task_comment);
            }
            else {
                current_group.find(".task-comment-form").html(data.html_task_comment_form);
            }
        }
    });
    form[0].reset();
    return false;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this one

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this one but unfortunately it didnt work for me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try to alert your csrf token.. if u will get any value?

Comment: How to check that value? In console? By the way, also after adding new task I have with message in console of my PyCharm: `UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context`

Comment: try to alert var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

Comment: Well I tried to add `alert(csrftoken);` in 2 place of my JS code. First: Before this comment `//TASK` and reload page it show me long string. Second: Then I tried to add `alert(csrftoken);` inside my `saveForm` function but it didnt show me any message when I add new task.

Comment: var saveForm = function () {    alert(csrftoken)  } try to alert here..

Comment: I add  alert(csrftoken)  as you said. I have long value when try to send comment by form but under the form I have error like "This field is required" even if I filled out the form. I am so comfused. I think problem is this argument data: { data: form.serialize(), csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')}, of saveForm function. What do you think about that?

Comment: maybe because I encountered that before, serialize and token together I'm getting error try not to serialize..

Comment: I have error message under form `This field is required` even if I filled out the form when dont use `form.serialize()`.

Comment: I dont have that message only when dont use `csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')` but in that case comments form raise error: `CSRF token missing or incorrect`. So comfused.

Comment: I tried this code `data: form.serialize().append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie(csrftoken))` inside my `saveForm` function. Unfortunatly I still have problems. Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: just try for example : 
        data: { id:id, name:name, csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrftoken }  since you initialize the var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); already. then check if you get any data

Comment: or try this var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'wordlist', value: wordlist});

data: { data: data }

Comment: I add `context.update(csrf(request))` inside of my view and `CSRF token missing or incorrect` error disappeared. But I still have problem when try to add comment to task inside that updated by AJAX list. In normal postition comment forms work well but they dont work when I try to send comment by one of the form in that upsated post. I update my post with view and JS code how do you think why such thing happans? Check my post again pls. I add code of my view and JS code.

Comment: do you have this ? <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: No I dont have this. Where it must be? I have inside comment form <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='long value'/>

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the token on the Ajax request:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

add this to your code after getCookie() call:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you say me in what part of my JS code I need to put `csrfSafeMethod` function and `$.ajaxSetup`? I am little bit comfused. Also I think my `data argument` of `saveForm` function is not corrent.

Comment: Paste all the the code below the line :    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');     It needs to run before the ajax call.

Comment: I put this code as you said below line `var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');` anyway I still have error. It seems to me I need to put `$.ajaxSetup` inside my `saveForm function`. What do you think about that?

Comment: I tried this code `data: form.serialize().append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie(csrftoken))` inside my saveForm function. Unfortunatly I still have problems. Do you have any ideas?!